# Custom Control to SharePoint Page Layouts

Tags: sharepoint-server, page-layout, user-controls

I have a custom user control.I want to add the following code at the time of activating feature in page layout.

```
<%@ Register Tagprefix="MyControls" Namespace="MyControl" 
  Assembly="MyControls, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XXX" %>

<MyControls:MyUserControl runat="server"/>
```

Comment: which following code?

Comment: @VarunVerma corrected the code formatting, now you can the code

Comment: Shubhashis, the control needs to be placed in a specific position on the page?

Comment: Thanks for reply..

I want to add one custom user control in the page layout programtically. I think to get that user control I have to add that register element in page layout.Hence I have to add that register element programtically.

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing is a modification of ASP.NET *markup* (not *code*), which I think is not the best way to handle this issue programmatically.

Better add or reuse a content placeholder and make this a [delegate control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb861966(v=office.12).aspx) if possible. You can find a how-to on MSDN: [How to: Customize a Delegate Control‎](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms470880(v=office.14).aspx).

You can read more on the architecture of SharePoint pages on MSDN: [Overview of the SharePoint 2013 page model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj191506(v=office.15).aspx).